# Simple RegEx check

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to prove wether there are special characters in a String or not. I tried this:

```
var keineSonderzeichen = /^([!\"\§\$\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\´\*\+\#\µ\.\,\:\;\<\>\|\²\³\{\}\\]{3,})$/;
```

and this:

```
var keineSonderzeichen = /^([!"§$%&/()=?´*+#µ.,:;<>|²³{}]{3,})$/;
```

than i ask for it with:

```
if(keineSonderzeichen.test(Input[i].value.toString()))
```

but it doesnt work... whats the mistake?

Comment: It doesn't work? What's happening?

Comment: "it doesn't work" tells us nothing. What results are you expecting, what results do you see instead, and why do those surprise you? What do your test strings look like?

Comment: the if always returns false also when i type in #######

Comment: @HansMueller: No, `/^([!\"\§\$\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\´\*\+\#\µ\.\,\:\;\<\>\|\²\³\{\}\\]{3,})$/.test("#######")` returns `true`.

Comment: yes but /^([!\"\§\$\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\´\*\+\#\µ\.\,\:\;\<\>\|\²\³\{\}\\]{3,})$/.test("abcd######‌​#") returns false

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it finds non-word characters and numbers

`var keineSonderzeichen = /[_\W0-9]/;`

but if you want to consider numbers as part of a valid string, just remove `0-9`

Comment: sry want to consider some non-word characters like @ and - as well

Comment: ok, this works fine I guess --> var keineSonderzeichen = /([^\w__@-__])/g;

Comment: but keineSonderzeichen.test(test-123) says true and keineSonderzeichen.test(#123) too

Comment: var keineSonderzeichen = /[^a-z0-9@-]/gi;

Answer (score 0):

`^` : stands for begining of string and
`$` for end of string.

You want to match special char anywhere in the string so remove the anchors.

```
var keineSonderzeichen = /([!"§$%&/()=?´*+#µ.,:;<>|²³{}]{3,})/;
```